# Dockerfile connect to ODBC(e.g. HPE Vertica) setup

Tags: ubuntu, docker, go, dockerfile, vertica

I have a simple **GO** program which successfully connects to Vertica in my ubuntu server. I have setup the **.dobc.ini** and **odbc drvier** in this ubuntu.

```
db, err := sql.Open("odbc", "DSN=HPVerticaDSN")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

log.Println("DB ping started...")
if err = db.Ping(); err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("DB ping failed with error...%v", err)
}
log.Println("DB connected.")
defer db.Close()
```

Now, How do I setup the *Dockerfile* to run this in docker container. Is it possible to use light weight base image like **alpine** or we have to use **ubuntu** base image. Any examples would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my **Dockerfile**

```
FROM alpine:latest
MAINTAINER Prataksha Gurung <prataksha.gurung@mydomain.net>
RUN apk add --no-cache ca-certificates
ADD libverticaodbc.so /libverticaodbc.so
ADD .odbc.ini ~/.odbc.ini
ADD main /usr/bin/main
ENTRYPOINT ["main"]
```

and I am getting

```
panic: standard_init_linux.go:178: exec user process caused "no such file or directory" [recovered]
panic: standard_init_linux.go:178: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
```

when I run this container.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I managed it to work with this dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:artful
MAINTAINER Prataksha Gurung <prataksha.gurung@mydomain.net>
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y curl
#downloading the relevant linux driver for this docker environment
RUN curl -O https://my.vertica.com/client_drivers/8.1.x/8.1.1-0/vertica-client-8.1.1-0.x86_64.tar.gz
RUN ls -la
RUN tar vzxf vertica-client-8.1.1-0.x86_64.tar.gz && rm vertica-client-8.1.1-0.x86_64.tar.gz
RUN apt-get install -y unixodbc-dev
ADD .odbc.ini /root/.odbc.ini         #-->your custom DNS setup
ADD vertica.ini /root/vertica.ini     #-->extra odbc driver setup
ADD main /usr/bin/main                #-->binary executable
ENTRYPOINT ["main"]
```